# Jquery Select2, Set Parameter Function from Result Controller to get ID or hit Jquery Select2

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, razor, jquery-select2

good day!

I little bit stuck to get value ID.

let's say, I have function select2

```
$("#select-vessel-name").select2({
                placeholder: "Type to find a Vessel",
                allowClear: true,
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                ajax: {
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    quietMillis: 100,
                    url: "@Url.Action("FetchVessel", "Vessel")",
                    data: function (searchTerm) {
                        return {
                            Date: $("#input_vessel_reportdate").val(),
                            query: searchTerm
                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data) {
                        return { results: data };
                    }
                },
                id: function (data) {
                    return data.UnitID;
                },
                multiple: false,
                formatResult: contractFormatResultUnit,
                formatSelection: contractFormatSelectionUnit,
                escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
            }).on("select2-opening", function () {
                $("#input_vessel_reportdate").datepicker('hide');
            });
```

if I click dropdown which is define the function, it will hit Vessel Controller and return the data.UnitID

my question is, how can I get /or hit the select2 function to return the data.unitID by passing parameter value "Date and query" below?

Maybe the screenshot will make you understand.

[image: I Need replacement ID]

[image: From ReplacementName]

I hope you understand my question.

I already google my problem, but I don't found something similar.

Thank you before.

Comment: did u try your above code? Is any error?

Comment: there is no error, if I create new data, the problem is, how can I trigger the function select2 bypassing parameter query : "test"

Comment: you set `minimumInputLength: 1` means if you type any letter inside select2 then it will hit your api with 2 params {date and query}  and it returns the result so let me know 1) you are not able to get that result? or 2) your api didn't receive those 2 params? or 3) if it work with single parameter?